# How to sort variables in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to sort a collection of items name alphabetically and display them in the page. My problem is the names contains numbers like

```
var items = [
    {‘name’ : ‘name 1’}, 
    {‘name’ : ‘name 2’}, 
    {‘name’ : ‘name 3’}, 
    …more  
    {‘name’ : ‘name 11’}, 
    {‘name’ : ‘name 12’},
    {‘name’ : ‘name 21’}, 
    {‘name’ : ‘name 22’}
]
```

Html

```
<div ng-repeat=“item in items | orderBy: ‘name’”>
   <h3> {{item.name}}</h3>
</div>
```

The result is like

```
name 1
name 11
name 12
name 2
name 21
name 22
```

I was hoping to have

```
name 1
name 2
name 3
name 11
name 12
name 21
name 22
```

Is there a quick way to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you change your data to make it "name 01"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: 'atoi(name.split(\' \')[1])'">
     <h3> {{item.name}}</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: It splits your string by space into array of 2 strings. Second element is our number as string. We parse it to integer using `atoi` method. This way angular sorts integers not strings.

Comment: but it doesn't work for the item that doesn't have numbers in the string correct?

Comment: Correct. Format of the items should be "text [space] number". Like in your example.

Comment: if those names are arbitrary and sometimes don't contain numbers , do I need to write my own sort function?

Comment: Then you need to understand first how you want to sort it. As now data is sorted by the number. After that you need to write custom function that will accept your item and will return something that angularjs can sort based on. In this example that function was `atoi(name.split(\' \')[1])`